# How to create a content management system using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to create a retail website of musical instruments just for practice. To summarize my project, Basically the customer can browse through the selection of instruments, while the admin has additional access to the Content Management System that I'm trying to do in the website. Then the admin can add or remove new/old products and has also an overview of all the items via Gridview.

The general idea for my CMS is, for example I have guitar brands called "Ibanez" and "Fender"(each having their own Griview since their database are separated). I created a webpage where the admin will require to fill up all the necessary details inside the textbox in order to create an item within "Ibanez" and "Fender" or to create entirely a new brand with new items. If the admin is already finish with the info, just click save and finally the new brand or new product will appear in the website. So let's say if the admin wants to create a new brand called "Gibson", the program should automatically create a gridview for that brand in the overview section of my website.

Now in order to achieve all this, What I did was when the admin hits save to create new brands or products, I created a code where it would modify/write new code in some of the project files. It is even programmed to create new files just by adding the .cs or .aspx extension, and then it will just use streamwriter to wirte the new code inside the new file.

Here is sample of my code where you write new code in a file:

```
 var gridViewLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx");
    var _gridViewLines = new List<string>(gridViewLines);
    int index = counter;
    index -= 1;

    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "    <h3>"+brand_name+" Guitar Items Data</h3>");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "    <div style=\"overflow:auto; width:1100px; max-height:500px;\">");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "      <asp:GridView ID=\"Guitar" + brand_name + "GridView\" runat=\"server\" CssClass=\"mydatagrid\" PagerStyle-CssClass=\"pager\" HeaderStyle-CssClass=\"header\" RowStyle-CssClass=\"rows\" AllowPaging=\"True\" AllowSorting=\"True\" AutoGenerateColumns=\"False\" CellPadding=\"3\" CellSpacing=\"3\" DataKeyNames=\"id\" DataSourceID=\"SqlDataSource"+brand_number+"\" OnRowDataBound=\"Guitar"+brand_name+"GridView_RowDataBound\" Height=\"250px\" Width=\"864px\">");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "          <Columns>");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "              <asp:TemplateField>");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                <ItemTemplate>");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                     <asp:Button ID=\"Guitar"+brand_name+"GridViewBtn\" runat=\"server\" Text=\"Delete\" OnClick=\"Guitar"+brand_name+"GridViewBtn_Click\"/>");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                </ItemTemplate>");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "              </asp:TemplateField>");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "              <asp:CommandField ButtonType=\"Button\" ShowEditButton=\"True\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"id\" HeaderText=\"id\" ReadOnly=\"True\" SortExpression=\"id\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"type\" HeaderText=\"type\" SortExpression=\"type\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"model\" HeaderText=\"model\" SortExpression=\"model\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"price\" HeaderText=\"price\" SortExpression=\"price\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"image1\" HeaderText=\"image1\" SortExpression=\"image1\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"image2\" HeaderText=\"image2\" SortExpression=\"image2\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"description\" HeaderText=\"description\" SortExpression=\"description\" ItemStyle-Wrap=\"false\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"neck_type\" HeaderText=\"neck_type\" SortExpression=\"neck_type\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"body\" HeaderText=\"body\" SortExpression=\"body\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"fretboard\" HeaderText=\"fretboard\" SortExpression=\"fretboard\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"fret\" HeaderText=\"fret\" SortExpression=\"fret\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"bridge\" HeaderText=\"bridge\" SortExpression=\"bridge\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"neck_pickup\" HeaderText=\"neck_pickup\" SortExpression=\"neck_pickup\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"bridge_pickup\" HeaderText=\"bridge_pickup\" SortExpression=\"bridge_pickup\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "                 <asp:BoundField DataField=\"hardware_color\" HeaderText=\"hardware_color\" SortExpression=\"hardware_color\" />");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "             </Columns>");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "         </asp:GridView>");
    _gridViewLines.Insert(index++, "      </div>");


    gridViewLines = _gridViewLines.ToArray();
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx", gridViewLines);
```

I was successful in this part but when i try to remove a brand, my code did not work and gave me an exception that it is still being used by another process.

Here is the code for removing some text in file:

```
public static void SearchRemove()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("    <h3>Gibson Guitar Items Data</h3>"))
            {
                break;
            }
            counter+=1;
        }
        file.Close();
        Remove(counter);

  }


    public static void Remove(int counter)
    {


                int removeAt = counter;//or any thing you want
                removeAt -= 1;
                int linesToRemove = 70; //or any thing you want
                string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx");
                List<string> arr = s.Split("\n".ToCharArray()).ToList();

                string result = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < linesToRemove; i++)
                {
                    arr.RemoveAt(removeAt);
                    result = "";
                    foreach (string str in arr)
                    {
                        result += str + "\n";
                    }

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\OverviewGuitarData.aspx", result);
                }
            }


    }
```

When I did not include the removing part, everthing is working fine. I was also informed later on that the approach that I'm doing is risky and not the right way a website works because the admin is modifying contents of a .cs or .aspx file. To be honest I'm stuck in thinking of a better way to do this so my questions is:

1.) How to achieve the above idea without modifying/writing a project file?

OR

2.) If I'm going to continue my previous approach. What algorithm to use if i want to delete the new code that i automatically implemented in the file without getting an exception that states that the process is still being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMSes usually store content in a database or a file system. The code (i.e. a `.cs` or an `.aspx` file) is not supposed to store *content*, it shall contain just the *program logic*.

Suggestions:

1. Store your content in a valid XML file. Example:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <brands>
       <brand name="Gibson">
           <items>
               ...
           </items>
       </brand>
   </brands>
   ```
2. Read the XML file from your ASP.NET program and deserialize it into objects. See also this MSDN topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx.
3. Fill your `GridView` or generally speaking your pages with the content you've just retrieved from the XML file.
4. Setup a watcher on the XML file so that when its content changes you could update your objects and render the new data on your website. See more information about `FileSystemWatcher` on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Having implemented these things, your site won't depend on the code for the contents, instead, it will update every time you update the XML file with the contents. Then you may explore how to store this information in a database instead, so that you could implement some back-end admin page to manage the contents (like most CMSes do).

Comment: great references! I'll definitely look into it. By the way, I've found the answer for question#2. It turns out that I just need to switch some methods in order to avoid having an exception. It's still not the right way but i guess that'll be enough for now while I'm still studying for question#1.